# varnish installation by pecl get error on whm

Tags: centos, varnish, pecl, whm

I'm trying to install varnish cache, which is oficially released via PECL:after that problem im also trying install varnish cache through command but it was also not successfull and we had get some error

```
    downloading varnish-1.1.1.tgz ...
Starting to download varnish-1.1.1.tgz (22,852 bytes)
........done: 22,852 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /root/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootSVST4d/varnish-1.1.1
running: /root/tmp/pear/temp/varnish/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for varnish support... yes, shared
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for varnish files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the varnish distribution
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/temp/varnish/configure' failed
The varnish.so object is not in /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
Tidying /usr/local/lib/php.ini...
No changes
Tidying /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/53/etc/php.ini...
No changes
```

Comment: Same error message when trying to install the PECL Varnish extension on Fedora (RedHat).

Answer (score 1):

You need install the varnish dev  packages.

In Ubuntu try install the package: libvarnishapi-dev

sudo apt-get install libvarnishapi-dev